# Question regarding the Galois group of $x^3-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

The splitting field is $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity.

Then the group $G=Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.

1. But what if the base field already contains $\omega$? What is $H=Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}(\omega))$?

My guess is $H=G$ because still the roots are not included in the base field of $H$, not quite sure.

2. And is it $G=S_3$ because $G\leq S_3$ since the degree of the polynomial is $3$ and the base field doesn't contain any of the roots, and it must contains the cyclotomic automorphism, or $3$-cycle, of order $3$, and the transposition that swaps complex conjugates, of order $2$? Is this reasoning correct?
3. If one of the roots lies on the base field, then should it start from $G\leq S_2$?

Comment: $H$ is $C_3$, acting by $k \mapsto (\sqrt[3]{2} \mapsto \sqrt[3]{2} \omega^k)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Why $H$ doesn't contain the transposition that swaps complex conjugates?

Comment: @user642721: that element of $G$ doesn't fix $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The roots are of the form $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega^n$. I think all of them are outside $H$ since it has irrational part?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you show it to me explicitly? I don't see why $3$-cycle fixes $H$ while the transposition doesn't.

Comment: The transposition sends $\omega$ to $\omega^2$, so it doesn't fix $\omega$ by definition. The $3$-cycle doesn't do anything to $\omega$ (and indeed it can't because it has order $3$ and the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ has degree $2$).

Comment: I thought the $3$-cycle sends $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega$ to $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2$, $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2$ to $\sqrt[3]{2}$, and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\sqrt[3]{2}\omega$. It looks like not fixing $H$... so confused

Comment: That's correct, it permutes the conjugates of $\sqrt[3]{2}$, but it doesn't do anything to $\omega$.

Comment: So we can't do something like $f(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega)=f(\sqrt[3]{2})f(\omega)$?

Comment: Ah now I see it was just $f(\omega)=\omega$, right? Thank you for being patient with me!

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been saying.